# Comparing enum to int, Calendar Class

Tags: java, calendar

Here is a doubt that's been puzzling me for a while.

Using the class Calendar in order to compare a Calendar enum valune, example:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

if (c.SUNDAY == c.getFirstDayOfWeek()); //US local
System.out.println("indeed");
```

So basically, I would like to know how it can be possible to actually compare an enum (SUNDAY) to getFirstDayOfWeek() method which returns an int.

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: `Calendar.SUNDAY` isn't an enum value, because `Calendar` (obviously enough) isn't an `enum`, it's a `class`. It's a `public static final int` - an integer constant. The javadocs would've told you thig.

Answer (score 1):

[**SUNDAY**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#SUNDAY) is a static final field in Calendar API. it isn't an enum. and [**getFirstDayOfWeek(**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getFirstDayOfWeek%28%29)) returns an int value(day of the week in int representation), thus the comparision is valid.

From [**Calendar Source:**](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Calendar.java.html)

```
576       public final static int SUNDAY = 1;
```

Comment: Ok even though I checked the API I was convinced they were set as enum. My bad, I had to search more in depth in order to overcome my doubt. Thanks.

Comment: @Rollerball API wodn't lie would it ??.. hehe, you can always check the source online :)

Answer (score 1):

c.SUNDAY is also an int (and not an Enum), so there's no problem.

Calendar final values are stored as int.

This way it creates a "common language" for all constants, when actual implementation (int) doesn't really matter.

[Calendar class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)